# Android Koin simple object inject fail

Tags: android, kotlin, koin

I'm trying to learn Koin for dependency injection in android. I started to follow the example and try to inject very simple object by but I'm getting the error as `NoBeanDefFoundException: No definition found for ...`

here's my code

**Gradle**

```
// Koin
    def koin_version = '2.0.1'
    implementation "org.koin:koin-androidx-scope:$koin_version"
    implementation "org.koin:koin-androidx-viewmodel:$koin_version"
    implementation "org.koin:koin-androidx-ext:$koin_version"
```

**Application onCreate()**

```
override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        startKoin{
            androidLogger()
            androidContext(this@Application)
            listOf(applicationModule)
        }

    }
```

**Modules.kt**

```
val applicationModule = module {
    factory { UserSession("email","password") }
}
```

but when I try to inject it in anywhere (Application, Activity, Fragment) as `private val userSession: UserSession by inject()` I get above mentioned error. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably got confused by the syntax, you're supposed to call the method `modules` and provide it with the modules you want started.

The `listOf` return value is ignored in your case, you're supposed to do something like this:

```
startKoin {
    androidLogger()
    androidContext(this@Application)
    modules(applicationModule)
}
```

[Reference](https://insert-koin.io/)

Answer (score 0):

try this.

KoinApp.kt

```
class KoinApp : MultiDexApplication() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        startKoin(this, listOf(appModule))
    }
}
```

appModule.kt

```
@JvmField
    val appModule = module {
         single { DataRepository(get()) } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer will work, but for future proofing, I would still have the list of.

```
startKoin {
androidLogger()
androidContext(this@Application)
modules(listOf(applicationModule))
```

}

Answer (score 0):

> Modules.kt:

```
val appModule = module {
    single { MyRepositoryImpl() }
}

val viewModelModule = module {
    viewModel { MainViewModel(get()) }
}
```

> MyApp.kt:

```
class MyApp : Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        startKoin {
            androidContext(this@MyApp)
            modules(listOf(appModule, viewModelModule))
        }
    }
}
```

> Go to AndroidManifest and add:

```
<application
      android:name=".MyApp"
      ...
</application>
```

> MainActivity.kt:

```
//ViewModel
private val vm:MainViewModel = get()
```